# sap.ui.unified.Shell with Standard SAPUI5 Routing

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

We were trying to implement multiple views in sap.ui.unified.shell content by using standard routing concept, but we dont know how to achieve this at code level.

When user clicks on home item in side pane home view should be loaded in content of shell.(Expecting bookmark url for home view)

MAIN.VIEW.XML:

```
<mvc:View
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m"
class="viewPadding">
    <u:Shell
        id="myShell">
        <u:headItems>
            <u:ShellHeadItem
                tooltip="Configuration"
                icon="sap-icon://menu2"
                press="handlePressConfiguration" />
            <u:ShellHeadItem
                tooltip="Home"
                icon="sap-icon://home"
                visible="false"
                press="" />
        </u:headItems>
        <u:headEndItems>
            <u:ShellHeadItem
                icon="sap-icon://log"
                tooltip="Logoff"
                press="" />
        </u:headEndItems>
        <u:user>
            <u:ShellHeadUserItem
                image="sap-icon://person-placeholder"
                username="Test User"
                press="" />
        </u:user>
        <u:search>
            <SearchField
                search="handleSearchPressed"/>
        </u:search>
        <u:paneContent>

        <List>
            <DisplayListItem
                label="Home"
                type="Navigation" />
            <DisplayListItem
                label="Page 1"
                type="Navigation" />
            <DisplayListItem
                label="Page 2"
                type="Navigation"/>
            <DisplayListItem
                label="Page 3"
                type="Navigation"/>
        </List>
        </u:paneContent>
    </u:Shell>
```

MAIN.CONTROLLER.JS:

```
handlePressConfiguration: function(oEvent) {
    var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
    var oShell = this.getView().byId("myShell");
    var bState = oShell.getShowPane();
    oShell.setShowPane(!bState);
    oItem.setShowMarker(!bState);
    oItem.setSelected(!bState);
},
```

Similarly, when user selects any of the side menu item, respective views should be loaded in content of shell.

Page1.view.xml should be loaded in shell content.(Expecting bookmark url for page1 view)

PAGE1.VIEW.XML:

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="shellproject.page1" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<Page title="Title">
    <content>
            <Text text=" Page 1 Contents Here.."/>
    </content>
</Page>
```

Page2.view.xml should be loaded in shell content.(Expecting bookmark url for page2  view)

PAGE2.VIEW.XML

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="shellproject.page2" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<Page title="Title">
    <content>
<Text text=" Page 2 Contents Here.."/>
    </content>
</Page>
```

[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5nuS.png)

[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XpTF.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since the control `sap.ui.unified.Shell` is deprecated as of SAPUI5 1.44.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann I don't think it's a valid reason to close as even if it's deprecated now, it wasn't before and could always be used

Comment: @Elikill58 The control `sap.ui.unified.Shell` has been deprecated **since Oct 2016.** In the context of SAP enterprise web applications developed with SAPUI5, deprecated controls and SAPUI5 versions that are out of maintenance pose security issues. There may be a few legacy applications still using `sap.ui.unified.Shell` but this question rather refers to new development based on the deprecated control.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann Warn about it is a good thing, but close because of it seems to don't be the better choice as talk in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280360/10952503). IMO it's a bad idea, but I didn't vote for it

Comment: This question refers to new development based on a dead control ("trying to implement [...] `sap.ui.unified.Shell`") rather than maintaining legacy code. SAPUI5 has strict compatibility rules. There is no value in keeping this question open while not receiving any answer and the question author himself not having visited SO since many years.